# wkhtmltopdf header html contentnotfound

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf

I want set a htm file to my pdf header, but i got ContentNotFound. I have checked the url of the html file (eventbymonth_header_firstpage.html) and it works normally the command line I am testing is:

D:\wkhtmltopdf.exe --page-width 297 --page-height 210 -T 50mm --header-html ['.../Site/reports/eventbymonth_header_firstpage.html'] ['...Site/reports/eventsbymonth.aspx?data=12/1/2013'] c:\testheader.pdf

![ContentNotFound - but the url is right . I am able to access it. What's wrong?][1]

Comment: `...Site` should be `../Site`?

Comment: I couldn't put localhost:port and etc when i create this question. But the url is the same and intead of "..." imagine local web server developer.